# Do you put #import s in .h or .m files?

Tags: objective-c

I wonder about Objective-C style.

I have FooClass.[hm] that depends on BarClass.[hm] for its implementation (though not for its interface). I can `#import "BarClass.h"` either directly in FooClass.m or indirectly through FooClass.h. I wonder about the common choice for this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should **ALWAYS** `#import` other classes in your `.m` file.

If they happen to also be members of your class, you can forward declare them (by using the `@class` directive) in your `.h` file.

The reason for doing this is because when you `#import` a `.h` file, you only want to import **declarations**, not **definitions**. By using `@class` and only `#import`ing in `.m` files, you are a) reducing overhead and b) makes for cleaner code.

Another reason you should do it this way was pointed out by [Matt Gallagher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36103/matt-gallagher):

> The reasoning behind forward declarations in header files is that it avoids unnecessary dependencies. i.e. Imagine B.h forward declares A and B.m imports A.h. Then imagine C.m, D.m, E.m and F.m import B.h. After all this is done, A.h changes. Since A is only forward declared in B.h, only B.m needs to rebuild. Without forward declarations, C.m, D.m, E.m and F.m would all need to be rebuild if A changes

Example:

**`.h` file:**

```
@class BarClass;

@interface FooClass : NSObject

...

@end
```

**`.m` file**

```
#import "BarClass.h"

@implementation FooClass

...

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for your categorical answer. I wonder if you can elaborate on the reasoning behind this answer.

Comment: The reasoning behind forward declarations in header files is that it avoids unnecessary dependencies.

i.e. Imagine B.h forward declares A and B.m imports A.h. Then imagine C.m, D.m, E.m and F.m import B.h. After all this is done, A.h changes. Since A is only forward declared in B.h, only B.m needs to rebuild. Without forward declarations, C.m, D.m, E.m and F.m would all need to be rebuild if A changes.

Comment: @Matt, you're right, i forgot about that one major point. I'll edit it in

Comment: So it's only about building speed then?

Comment: If you use a delegate as a class variable, you may have to use `#import` instead of `@class` in the header file. Other than that, this is generally good advice.

Comment: @iter no, it's not just about build speed.  It's also about circular dependencies.  If A.h imports B.h and B.h imports A.h you'll get errors due to undefined references in one or other of the files.

Comment: And what about protocols ? Should they be imported in .h file or .m file ?

Comment: I'm very confused by this answer. I am using an instance of a class I created (Level) as a @property of my other class, GameController. If I remove the `#import "Level.h"` from the header file and place it in the implementation file, the property declaration gives an error. What am I misunderstanding about your explanation? Is this where I should be using forward declarations?

Comment: What does "If they happen to also be members of your class, you can forward declare them (by using the @class directive) in your .h file" mean? How is a class a 'member' of another class?

Answer (score 0):

**#import in .h or .m files**

- `.h` file - public `interface` of a class
- `.m` file - private `implementation` of the class

My rules are:

- Forward declaration[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59211124/4770877) - `@class` inside `.h` file
- You should reduce of imports in `.h`
- The accent should be on import in `.m` file that prevents dependency issues

When you need something in `implementation` then you should import it in `.m`. When you need something in `interface` then you should import it in `.h`.

[[import angle brackets `<>` and quote marks `""`]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59197871/4770877)