# Objective-C: Forward Class Declaration

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, forward-declaration

I'm writing a multiview app that utilizes a class called `RootViewController` to switch between views.

In my `MyAppDelegate` header, I create an instance of the `RootViewController` called `rootViewController`. I've seen examples of such where the @class directive is used as a "forward class declaration," but I'm not quite sure what this means or accomplishes.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class RootViewController;
@interface MyAppDelegate
.
.
.
```

Comment: My guess is that you don't "create an instance of", as much as "declare a pointer to". Is this correct?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It basically tells the compiler that the class `RootViewController` exists, without specifying what exactly it looks like (ie: its methods, properties, etc). You can use this to write code that includes `RootViewController` member variables without having to include the full class declaration.

This is particularly useful in resolving circular dependencies - for example, where say `ClassA` has a member of type `ClassB*`, and `ClassB` has a member of type `ClassA*`. You need to have `ClassB` declared before you can use it in `ClassA`, but you also need `ClassA` declared before you can use it in `ClassB`. Forward declarations allow you to overcome this by saying to `ClassA` that `ClassB` exists, without having to actually specify `ClassB's` complete specification.

Another reason you tend to find lots of forward declarations is some people adopt a convention of forward declaring classes unless they absolutely must include the full declaration. I don't entirely recall, but possibly that's something that Apple recommends in it's Objective-C guiding style guidlines.

Continuing my above example, if your declarations of `ClassA` and `ClassB` are in the files `ClassA.h` and `ClassB.h` respectively, you'd need to `#import` whichever one to use its declaration in the other class. Using forward declaration means you don't need the `#import`, which makes the code prettier (particularly once you start collecting quite a few classes, each of which would need an `#import where it's used), and increases compiling performance by minimising the amount of code the compiler needs to consider while compiling any given file.

As an aside, although the question is concerned solely with forward declarations in Objective-C, all the proceeding comments also apply equally to coding in C and C++ (and probably many other languages), which also support forward declaration and typically use it for the same purposes.

Comment: So, I guess I'm confused as to why creating a RootViewController object in the MyAppDelegate.h isn't enough. Seems redundant, but I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental. ... EDIT: Ah; just saw your edit.

Comment: Excellent. Succinct. Thank you.

Comment: One reason to forward declare classes is if A has a pointer to B which has as pointer to A. You can't import A.h from B.h AND B.h from A.h because it is a circular dependency. Forward declaration in header files takes care of that. A.m imports B.h. B.m imports A.h.

Comment: @RogerWernersson: is that not exactly what my answer says?

Comment: Then, can we use @class instead of import for every other case? Or what kind of case would absolutely need import and cannot be done with @class?

Answer (score 4):

Forward declarations are mainly to avoid circular imports, where one file imports another file which imports the first file etc. Basically when you import a file, contents of the file are substituted at the point of import when you build your project, which is then fed to the compiler. If you have circular imports, you'd have an infinite loop which would never compile. Fortunately xcode will tell you about this before trying. The forward declaration says "Don't import this class but just know that it exists. " Without either an import or a forward declaration, you get an error that no such class exists.

Answer (score 2):

`@class` or `forward class declaration`(incomplete type) - just tell to a compiler that this class exists. In this case the compiler **does not** know anything about type memory layout - class size, members, or methods. That is why you can only use for defining classes via references and pointers.

Advantages:

- reduce build time
- break cyclic references