# Circular #import Reference

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a Xcode project where I have to transfer Data from my `SettingsViewController` to my `ViewController`, the Problem is that I have to implement my `SettingsViewController.h` in my `ViewController`, because it gets pushed out of that - but to send data from the `SettingsViewController` to `ViewController` I have to implement the ViewController in `SettingsViewcontroller` too thats when the Program gets stuck - it's not possible having a circular `#import` reference, isn´t it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use forward declaration in all the .h files then and import the files in .m files

Check this question
[Objective-C: Forward Class Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191487/objective-c-forward-class-declaration)

A forward declaration looks like this:

```
@class SettingsViewController;
```

Comment: Could you give me a code example for forward declaration please?

Comment: Also make sure that both object don't have strong (retain) pointers to each other, creating what is called a "retain cycle".