# Circular #import, did I do it wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got confused a bit about importing in Objective-C, thus I wanna make sure about something:

I have A.h and A.m, B.h and B.m, I currently added `#import "B.h"` in **A.m**, and `#import "A.h"` in **B.h**, It's working, no warning or error, but would this create any problem?

Reason I cant use `@class` is because I declare a protocol and an enum in A.h, and use it B.h, `@class` cannot catch that

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular #import Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994286/circular-import-reference)

Comment: You can use forward declaration like this. :)

Comment: @ShamasS I knew about `@class`, but I cant use that, since I declare a protocol and enum in A.h, and use it B.h, `@class` cannot catch that, probably its different cased than the other question

Comment: It never matters what you include in `.m` files. With a good class architecture you won't have problems with circular dependencies. This is very similar to avoiding retain cycles. Parent should include its children and children should not include the parent - and if they do, they need to use a forward declaration.

Comment: Thanks, actually, I import A.h in B.h, but i don't touch anything of class A, just because i declare a protocol in there and i want to use it, I think the safest route is to create another header file for protocol but this question is just to make sure

Answer (score 0):

> #import ensures that a file is only ever included once so that you never have a problem with recursive includes. However, most decent
>   header files protect themselves against this anyway

From [What is the difference between #import and #include in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c)
If you are using #import it doesn't matter much in case where a file is recursively adding each other.