# Cocos2D/iOS: usage of "@class Component" tag

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, components

I am using Cocos2d 2.x and iOS 5.0.

Could anyone share with me a good tutorial or explanation on the usage of **"@class Component" tag?**

Is there any design/patter that refers to it or does it do something more specific to the code?

I haven't found much on my [google search](https://www.google.it/search?q=@class%20Component;&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3ait%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=AoV&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3ait%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22@class%20Component%22%20ios&oq=%22@class%20Component%22%20ios&gs_l=serp.3...30367.30367.2.30846.1.1.0.0.0.0.148.148.0j1.1.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.5sue5gIwstM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bGE&fp=1585625df7f66034&bpcl=40096503&biw=1280&bih=587).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is that normally if you reference a class in an interface, you have to #import that class' header file:

```
#import "OtherClass.h"

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
   OtherClass* someOtherClass;
}
@end
```

The @class statement allows you to skip importing the header:

```
@class OtherClass;

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
   OtherClass* someOtherClass;
}
@end
```

You still have to #import "OtherClass.h" in the implementation file if you use @class.

```
// Still need to import, but now any class importing MyClass.h 
// does not automatically know about OtherClass as well.

#import "OtherClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
…
@end
```

When you #import "MyClass.h" somewhere else in a third class, that third class does not automatically include the header of the OtherClass class if you have used @class OtherClass; in the MyClass header. Therefore the third class has no knowledge of OtherClass unless it expressly imports the OtherClass.h header. This is helpful when writing a public API that should hide its implementation details (ie OtherClass) from the developer.

Forward declaration is considered good practice (if only because it has no downsides other than a slightly altered workflow) and is preferable to importing the class' header in another header file. This certainly helps prevent cyclic imports as mentioned by Phillip.

I don't know about Xcode but in Visual Studio (C++) class forwarding was also instrumental to speed up compilation in larger projects with hundreds of classes. That was because the VS C++ compiler spent quite some time resolving header dependencies

Answer (score 3):

`@class` just tells the compiler that the name following it is the name of an Objective-C class.  It's used in .h files when it's necessary to define a symbol of that type but where importing the entire definition would either be overkill or cause an actual problem.  (For example, two classes that each refer to the other.)

Comment: The official term for this is "forward declaration". Also discussed in detail over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191487/objective-c-forward-class-declaration