# SpriteKit -use of AppDelegate - undeclared identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, appdelegate

I'm writing the game in cocos2d (from Pablo Ruiz's book).
Right now I have to create pause screen, and, according to the book, I have to create new function in AppDelegate.m (and in .h file) :

```
+(AppDelegate *) get {

return (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

I'm getting errors : Expected a type; expected expression; Missing '[' at start of message send expression; Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'.

In another file, called GameScene.m, I created those functions:

```
-(void)resume
{
if(![AppDelegate get].paused)
{
    return;
}
[AppDelegate get].paused = NO;
[self onEnter];
}

-(void)onExit
{
if(![AppDelegate get].paused)
{
    [AppDelegate get].paused = YES;
    [super onExit];
}
}

-(void)onEnter
{
if(![AppDelegate get].paused)
{
    [super onEnter];
}
}
```

And I'm getting another set of errors : Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate', four times.

Can someone explain me how to get rid of those errors?

Comment: Do you `#import` your AppDelegate properly in your GameScene file?

Comment: Tip: if you learn from a book, be sure to use the EXACT same version of the software described/used in the book. If you get this issue resolved, there'll be dozens of similar ones waiting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d 2.0? Then Use AppController.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppController *app = (AppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it tomorrow, and I will tell you if it helps. But what about that eroor about missing type?

Comment: Nothing helps. Whatever I do, I still recieve the same errors. Can someone give me the solution, because I don't know it

Comment: can you tell me how to use AppController in my program I posted above?

Comment: JUST LIKE IN MY ANSWER. Also put paused property if required..there is no default property like [AppDelegate get].paused I guess...you need to write one in appDelegate if required.

Comment: But where to use this "app"? I created the "paused" property, and still getting those errors

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the following to your GameScene.h:

```
@class AppDelegate;
```

This will let the compiler know that the class `AppDelegate` exists.
And in your GameScene.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

This lets you access AppDelegate members and methods.

Comment: Thanks, it solved a few issues, but there are more. First, I got errors : Receiver 'AppDelegate' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist; Property 'paused' cannot be found in forward class object 'AppDelegate'. Those two errors are repeated 5 times each). And there is one more error, concerning AppDelegate.m - Expected a type.

Comment: That sounds as if you are trying to access members of your `AppDelegate` in a .m file that does not #import AppDelegate. Try to add the #import in the header file as well. This is not a good style and you should try to avoid it. Familiarize yourself with the concept of forward declaration. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5191507/921573

Comment: Hello. I have imported everything in every place, and still nothing. Still I recieve errors that I mentioned at the beggining. What to do?

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to guess now...maybe you have forgotten to add some library or framework to you build phase? (Select your project file from the navigator, select your target, select build phases, check target dependencies / link binary with libraries)

Comment: I checked everything. I also tried to rename every AppDelegate to AppController, but it doesn't work either