# How to get rootViewController in iOS 13 using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscenedelegate, uiwindowscene

I'm trying to get the `rootViewController` in iOS 13 using Objective-C. I'm doing something like this:

```
for (UIScene *scene in UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes) {
    UIWindowScene *windowScene = (UIWindowScene *) scene;
    UIWindowSceneDelegate *windowSceneDelegate = (UIWindowSceneDelegate *) windowScene.delegate;
    windowSceneDelegate.window = ...
}
```

But when I try to access the `window` property in `windowSceneDelegate.window =` (to get the `rootViewController`) I get the following error:

> Property 'window' cannot be found in forward class object 'UIWindowSceneDelegate'

But when I go to the definition of `UIWindowSceneDelegate`, I see a `window` property:

[image]

So what is the right way get rootViewController in iOS 13 using Objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to:

```c
for (UIScene *scene in UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes) {
    if ([scene.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIWindowSceneDelegate)]) {
        UIWindow *window = [(id<UIWindowSceneDelegate>)scene.delegate window];
    }
}
```

When you open the `UIKit`s `UIWindowScene.h` header file, it contains:

```c
@class UIScreen, UIWindow, UIWindowSceneDelegate, UISceneDestructionRequestOptions, CKShareMetadata, UISceneSizeRestrictions;
```

See, there's the `UIWindowSceneDelegate`. This is the forward declaration.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191507/581190) to learn what the forward declaration is.