# Why the order in which you write declare and use functions in C# doesn't matter contrary to C++

Tags: c#, c++

I was wondering, when I write code in C# Unity for my games, I can declare voids in the code **after** using them, and the code still works. When I write pure C++ code on the other hand, I need to declare my functions **before** using them, and I am very curious why is that difference present?

Comment: "and I am very curious why is that difference present?" - because C++ was designed at a time when compilers only did 1 pass through source-code, while the C# language was designed after compilers could do multi-pass runs.

Comment: Also, the fact you're using Unity is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Dai so the difference comes from C# itself, and not the fact that I am using the Unity game engine?

Comment: Unity uses the same C# compiler (`csc.exe`) as the rest of the .NET ecosystem. Unity is just a _host_ for the .NET CLR, in much the same way that JavaScript can run in the browser or in a headless process (NodeJS).

Comment: @Dai alright, thanks, that is the answer I was seeking.

Comment: Note that class member functions can be used by other members of the class, without being forward declared. The rule is there only for free  functions (which is what C has).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering, when I write code in C# Unity for my games, I can declare voids in the code after using them, and the code still works. When I write pure C++ code on the other hand, I need to declare my functions before using them, and I am very curious why is that difference present?

**Short answer**:

- Because C++ and C# are completely different programming languages with their own entirely separate backstories and compilers.
- Because C++ was built on-top of C and inherited its compilation process.
- ...and C was designed at a time when compilers only did 1 pass through source-code with minimal RAM usage which necessitates forward-declarations, while C# was designed when compilers could do "multi-pass" runs and build large in-memory program models which obviated the need for forward-declaration.

**Longer answer**:

Note that by "multi-pass" I don't mean that the compiler actually re-parses and processes source-files from-scratch multiple times; what it means is that after the C# compiler has parsed the source-code (which only happens once), it can extract out all the *symbols for things* (like types, methods, etc) that are actually used by a program and store that in a list in memory (`list-of-used-things`) and only complain about missing/broken references after it's built-up a list of everything that is fully defined by the program (`list-of-defined-things`) and compared the two lists. Whereas back in the 1970s and early 1980s computers simply didn't have enough memory to store those lists-of-things, hence why C requires it.

<sub>Now, today in 2021, arguably *it is possible* to have a C (and even a C++ compiler) that doesn't need forward-declarations, however that's another topic concerned with too many reasons I won't go into (though the main reason is probably because *there simply isn't any demand*:  all existing C and C++ programs already have forward-declarations and no-one will write a C or C++ program without forward-declarations just because a single compiler supports it. The ISO C and C++ language design committees could introduce it, but because forward-declarations are fundamental to C's language design it would be a truly massive breaking-change to the wider C and C++ ecosystem and everyone would complain.</sub>

C++ was built on-top of C, and so it inherited its requirement for forward-declaration. C++'s compatibility with C source-code was a huge positive factor for C++'s popularity compared to other OOP languages at the time (like Smalltalk and Object Pascal) which would require existing C programs to be either completely ported-over to a new language or require C programs to be linked in binary form, which complicates everything.

<sub>Objective-C is another OOP language built on-top of C, and it too, [inherits C's requirement for forward-declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191487/objective-c-forward-class-declaration).</sub>

Arguably C++ *could* have been designed to be able to be compiled without forward-declarations however that would add a ton of complexity w.r.t. its compatibility with C source files, as well as almost certainly delaying the release date of C++ itself because hammering out the specification for exactly how *C-compatible-compilation-without-forward-declaration* should work would take months or even years to complete.

Flash forward to the mid-1990s with Java (and eventually C#) and these modern programming languages are not intended to be source-compatible with C programs *at all* (the shared curly-brace syntax notwithstanding), which means those languages don't need to be designed around limitations imposed by contemporaneous hardware limitations.

<sub>This isn't to say that the ergonomic design of the Java language wasn't compromised by its compiler design: Java *still* requires [1-type-per-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968347/can-a-java-file-have-more-than-one-class) and the `CLASSPATH`/`SOURCEPATH` bollocks. I understand these restrictions were necessary for Java's then very fast and simple compiler, and it does mean that all Java projects will have a predictable layout, but 25+ years later these restrictions are increasingly seen as imposing a very tedious burden on programmers and are overall silly restrictions with little benefit. However compare that to post-Java languages like C#, Rust, Kotlin, Go, Swift which entirely decouple a project's source-code arrangement from the compiled output.</sub>

---

I assume you've read this: [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) - if you haven't read it, then you should read it first.

Now, consider this table and spot the correlation:

| Language | C | C++ | Java | C# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vintage | [1972](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) | [1985-ish](https://www.cplusplus.com/info/history/) | [1995](https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-history/) | [2001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history) |
| Exemplary contemporaneous typical workstation | [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture) | [HP 200 Series](https://www.hpmuseum.net/exhibit.php?class=1&cat=1) | [SPARCstation 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARCstation_10) | [Beige box](https://web.archive.org/web/20011205190922/http://www.dell.com/us/en/bsd/products/model_precn_3_precn_340.htm) |
| [RAM Cost: USD per MiB](https://jcmit.net/memoryprice.htm) | N/A | $1,000 | $32 | $4 |
| Typical RAM in said contemporaneous typical workstation | [56 KiB](https://history-computer.com/dec-pdp-11-computer/) | 512 KiB | 32 MiB | 128 MiB |
| Single-pass compiler | Yes | Yes | No | No |
| Requires forward declarations | Yes | Yes | No | No |
| Language ergonomics | Basic | Awful | Good | Very good |

In conclusion: the more RAM a compiler can use means the more ergonomic a language can be, because the fundamental design of a programming language doesn't need to be compromised by limitations imposed on the parser/compiler/linker from having insufficient memory.

Comment: "Language ergonomics" ahhh.. that hurts...