# How do I make my class conform to an external protocol? It can't find it but I was under the impression I shouldn't import in .h files

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, protocols

I defined a protocol in `ClassA`, and want `ClassB` to conform to it, so in `ClassB` I have `<ClassADelegate>`.

It keeps complaining, however, that it can't find that specific protocol. I understand why, I'm claiming to conform to a protocol in the .h file, but that class is `#import`ed in the .m file, so it doesn't know about it yet.

So I tried a forward `@class` declaration, and even a forward `@protocol` declaration, but neither one worked, it still doesn't know about the protocol I'm specifying.

My only option left seems to be to import it in the .h file instead of the .m file, but [everything I've heard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863855/objective-c-importing-headers-in-h-or-m) indicates that you shouldn't be importing in the .h, I've been personally bit by circular reference bugs and I'm very hesitant to do this.

What should I do?

Comment: You have to import the .h that defines the protocol into the .h that uses the protocol.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy. If you're worried about circular references, you can always take the protocol out of `ClassA` and give it its very own `.h` file which should be safe to import into other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and building it. I had similar problems and doing a clean build fixed the issue.