# What is difference between a class & class interface in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

If both are same & then why we were calling like this in Objective C?

Please clarify this.

Comment: could just paste two simple pieces of code to understand what you are referring to?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019961/objective-c-class-directive-before-interface) answers your questions?

Comment: hi.....i didn't write any code .now i am learning the objective-c , i have doubt at reading tutorial thats why i asking yours

Comment: What do you mean by 'class' and 'class interface'? There's no such thing as a 'class interface' in Objective-C... It ain't Java...

Answer (score 2):

@class is used for [forward reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019961/objective-c-class-directive-before-interface), to stop cyclic calls.

Class interface i.e., @interface is used to create a blue print / .h / declaration of a class.

Comment: thanks Mr.AKV .what i want to exactly is it follows.

Comment: +1 **this** is the correct answer, the other one doesn't mention forward declaration and it incorrectly assumes stylistic differences...

Answer (score 0):

`@Class` is used when we only want to declare the object of any class.

For example:

```
in .h file

@class Mindfire;

@interface MindfireSolutions :UIViewController
{
   Mindfire*   _mindfire;

}
```

This is done because neither we want to use the methods of the `Mindfire` class at this time nor we want to set the delegate of the `Mindfire` class. Hence we can use this to increase the compiler speed.

In the .m file, do not forget this step to use the methods of this class or to access the variables of this class:

```
#import Mindfire.h
#import MindfireSolution.h


@implementation MindfireSolution

-
-
-

@end
```

Now we have done this because we will use the methods of this class in .m only.

`#import` is always used when we want to use the methods of any class or we want to set a delegate for that class.

For example, in the .h file:

```
#import Mindfire.h

@interface MindfireSolutions:UIViewController<MindfireDelegate>
{
   Mindfire*   _mindfire;
}
```

`#import` is used in a .h file only when we are setting the delegate for any class.

Comment: @iPatel, are you aware that the formatting is totally messed up?