# missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int on function in .h file

Tags: c++, sfml

I am following tutorials outlined in "SFML Game Development" by Packt Publishing.  In chapter 4, I am having many errors, most notably " missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int".  Here is my header and source file that this is referring to:

```
#pragma once

#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Category.h"
#include "Command.h"

class SceneNode : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable, private sf::NonCopyable
{
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<SceneNode> Ptr;

public:
    SceneNode();
    void attachChild(Ptr);
    Ptr detachChild(const SceneNode&);
    void update(sf::Time);
    sf::Transform getWorldTransform() const;
    sf::Vector2f getWorldPosition() const;
    unsigned int getCategory() const;
    void onCommand(const Command&, sf::Time);

private:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget&, sf::RenderStates) const;
    virtual void drawCurrent(sf::RenderTarget&, sf::RenderStates) const;
    virtual void updateCurrent(sf::Time);
    void updateChildren(sf::Time);

private:
    std::vector<Ptr> mChildren;
    SceneNode* mParent;
};

#include "SceneNode.h"


SceneNode::SceneNode() : mChildren(), mParent(nullptr)
{

}

void SceneNode::attachChild(Ptr child)
{
    child->mParent = this;
    mChildren.push_back(std::move(child));
}
SceneNode::Ptr SceneNode::detachChild(const SceneNode& node)
{
    auto found = std::find_if(mChildren.begin(), mChildren.end(), [&] (Ptr& p) -> bool
    {
        return p.get() == &node;
    });
    assert(found != mChildren.end());

    Ptr result = std::move(*found);
    result->mParent = nullptr;
    mChildren.erase(found);
    return result;
}

void SceneNode::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    states.transform *= getTransform();
    drawCurrent(target, states);
    for(auto itr = mChildren.begin(); itr != mChildren.end(); ++itr)
    {
        (*itr)->draw(target, states);
    }
}

void SceneNode::drawCurrent(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
}

void SceneNode::updateCurrent(sf::Time dt)
{

}
void SceneNode::update(sf::Time dt)
{
    updateCurrent(dt);
    updateChildren(dt);
}
void SceneNode::updateChildren(sf::Time dt)
{
    for(auto itr = mChildren.begin(); itr != mChildren.end(); ++itr)
    {
        (*itr)->update(dt);
    }
}

sf::Transform SceneNode::getWorldTransform() const
{
    sf::Transform transform = sf::Transform::Identity;
    for(const SceneNode* node = this; node != nullptr; node = node->mParent)
    {
        transform = node->getTransform() * transform;
    }
    return transform;
}
sf::Vector2f SceneNode::getWorldPosition() const
{
    return getWorldTransform() * sf::Vector2f();
}

unsigned int SceneNode::getCategory() const
{
    return Category::Scene;
}

void SceneNode::onCommand(const Command& command, sf::Time dt)
{
    if(command.category & getCategory())
    {
        command.action(*this, dt);
        for(auto itr = mChildren.begin(); itr != mChildren.end(); ++itr)
        {
            (*itr)->onCommand(command, dt);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is specifically on line 23:

```
void onCommand(const Command&, sf::Time);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: N.B: `#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>` should be `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`, even on MS-DOS based computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the file "Command.h" also includes this file... If that's the case, `#pragma once` doesn't do exactly what you'd expect, and you end up not having declared the class `Command` by the time you try to declare the `onCommand` member function.

Just add forward class declarations before your `SceneNode` class declaration, and you should be fine:

```
class Command;

class SceneNode : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable, private sf::NonCopyable
{
    // etc.
};
```

You're seeing an error because the compiler hasn't seen the type `Command` yet, tries to fall back on `int`, and then realizes that C++ doesn't allow that anymore. (hat tip:@Lightness Races in Orbit)

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20590646/2905299) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20590599/2905299) for a more detailed explanation. (Just for reference, the `#import` directive in Objective-C acts like `#include` plus `#pragma once`, so the logic is the same.)

Comment: Add that this error is the compiler failing to find the type, trying to fall back on `int` to make up for it, then realising that C++ doesn't allow that nowadays.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  Command is actually a struct, so struct Command; worked.  :)

Comment: @Charsmud Happy to help... Happy New Year!

Comment: @Charsmud: The keywords `struct` and `class` both define types (the only distinction being some semantic differences in default access levels during type definition): there is no further distinction at this point. So here they are interchangeable. No such thing as "a struct" vs "a class".

Answer (score 0):

This specific compiler error usually means that you've somehow screwed up a variable declaration, typically by using an unknown type or by malforming the line some other way.

Since `sf::Time` will be defined by the other SFML headers (in this case `SFML/Graphics.hpp`), this can't be the problem. Due to this, `Command` is most likely the culprit. However, to determine the exact reason without guessing, you'd have to post the contents of your `Command.h` file as well.