# Duplicate symbol error in Xcode Build

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

`duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MainPageScreenCollectionReusableView._mainPageScreenHeaderLabel in:     /Users/bharathbalaraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SentientiOS-anuolaqayswdbzakppukvtjatylz/Build/Intermediates/SentientiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SentientiOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainPageScreenCollectionReusableView-9480B7CE5B075E6A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainPageScreenCollectionReusableView in:     /Users/bharathbalaraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SentientiOS-anuolaqayswdbzakppukvtjatylz/Build/Intermediates/SentientiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SentientiOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainPageScreenCollectionReusableView-9480B7CE5B075E6A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainPageScreenCollectionReusableView in:     /Users/bharathbalaraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SentientiOS-anuolaqayswdbzakppukvtjatylz/Build/Intermediates/SentientiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SentientiOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainPageScreenCollectionReusableView-9480B7CE5B075E6A.o 
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` ..

I am getting this error when I compile in xcode. Not sure how this is coming. Does anyone have a clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You have added to the project same file multiple times. This usually happens when you add file to project, remove and then add it again.

The file causing this issue is `MainPageScreenCollectionReusableView`.

To resolve this issue go to Target-> Build phases-> in search field enter `MainPageScreenCollectionReusableView` and remove red ones.

Comment: i got it resolved.. actually there was a red marked file with that name present in one of the folders of the project. It had been removed from the folder but it was still showing on xcode in red color.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error and it was #import loop (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223914/objective-c-import-loop))

You may need to change few `#imports` in `.h` files to `@class` and make actual `#imports` in `.m` files.