# Objective C - Avoid Import Loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, import

I want to connect two classes of mine and link each other with a property of each class. I broke down the main aspects to this example:

Ocean.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Fish.h"

@interface Ocean : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *listOfFishesInOcean;
@end
```

Fish.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Ocean.h"

@interface Fish : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) Ocean *homeOcean;    // Compiler: "Unknown type name Ocean"
@property (nonatomic) int age;
@end
```

What I wanna do in the end, is to manipulate the age property of an Fish object and be able to save it (listOfFishesInOcean, NSUserDefaults), as well as call a function in the Ocean object, when saving is completed. This way I'd always have the latest list of Fish-objects in my list of the Ocean-object.

My two problems here are:

1. How to avoid the [import-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223914/objective-c-import-loop), which causes the complier error, I think?
2. How should I implement the save & action workflow in the end?

I thought about solving this issue with notifications and observer but this way I'd still need to filter the notifications in any way, due to the fact that I've multiple Oceans with more Fishes.
Another idea to solve it, would be to give each Ocean object and Fish object an ID, which I would use as a key in NSUserDefaults again.

If anyone has some thoughts about it or other ideas, you are very welcome!

Comment: I wrote an answer with a proposal for first and the answer to your question  at the end

Comment: Create a single Header file (Constants.h) and import all files in it, then simply import that file, or you can import files in your `.pch` file which is by default accessible in all Classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import ".h" files only in ".m" file, like:

Ocean.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Fish;

@interface Ocean : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *listOfFishesInOcean;
@end
```

Ocean.m file:

```
#import "Ocean.h"
#import "Fish.h"

 @implementation Ocean

@end
```

Fish.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Ocean;

@interface Fish : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) Ocean *homeOcean;    
@property (nonatomic) int age;
@end
```

Fish.m file:

```
#import "Fish.h"
#import "Ocean.h"

 @implementation Fish

 @end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the best approaches could be using the identifiers so you improve the performance.

```
@interface Ocean : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) int identifier;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *listOfFishesInOcean;
@end

@interface Fish : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) int age;
@property (nonatomic) int parent_identifier;
@end
```

if you want to keep your approach:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Ocean;

@interface Fish : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) Ocean *homeOcean;    // Compiler: "Unknown type name Ocean"
@property (nonatomic) int age;
@end
```

#### Fish.m

```
#import "Ocean.h"
```

Comment: Nice thanks for the two solutions now it's working! Another related topic pointed to the usage of IDs is, what happens when I'll keep my approach and save the Ocean  object in NSUserDefaults (-> encodeWithCoder) and the Ocean will call encodeWithCoder in Fish again. This would lead to a loop due to the both properties in each classes I think, won't it?

Comment: I suggest using core data since user default is for small and quick data since bool flags and so on.