# Objective-C Class Question?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, ios, methods

My head is about to explode with this logic, can anyone help?

Class A #imports Class B.
Class A calls Method A in Class B.

This works great

Class B wants to send a response back to Class A from another method that is called from Method A. If you #import Class A from Class B, it is in effect an infinite loop and the whole thing crashes.

Is there a way to do this properly, like a parent type thing?

BTW, I'm developing for iPhone.

**EDIT**
When i #import Class A from Class B i get this compiler error...

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'StoreHoursCore'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's __not__ creating an infinite loop. The `#import` directive prevents a file from being included more than once. Please describe the compilation error you get from doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that using the `@class` directive should solve your issue.

Using `@class` **forward declares** your class type in order that the compiler doesn't cough.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import) on SO.

Comment: I would add that this is called "forward declararion"

Comment: you keep typing the same thing seconds before I do :/

Comment: @Brock, who? Me, or @Vladimir?

Comment: @Jacob Lol. Yeah what a coincidence!

Comment: I would add that it's good practice to use #import only in the implementation file and to use the @class otherwise. The exception to this is when you have to import the header for a super class. It's not a hard and fast rule but it is the habit you should get into.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@class`to forward declare it as a class. This hints the compiler to know that it is a class, without having to cross include and compile the class multiple times (the reason you are getting your error). ie:

```
@class myClass;
```

The `#import`preprocessor directive has protection against multiple includes, but the `#include` directive does not.