# Objective-C Xcode: Prefix.pch question?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, pch

I have two files independant on each other.

Let's just call it Class1 and Class2.

In Class1, I need Class2, and in Class2 I need Class1.

I have a prefix file where I include all my files, and I get some syntax errors because I do

```
#import "Class1.h"
#import "Class2.h"
```

How would I define both of them so they can use each other?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into using a [forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import). Replace the `#import` of `Class2` in `Class1` with `@class Class2;` and move this `#import` statement to the implementation `Class1.m` (and vice versa).