# @class vs #import

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference when using @class or #import in objective-c?

I have seen various tutorials and only a few use @class while most of the others use #import.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C @class vs. #import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`@class` doesn't import the file, it just says to the compiler "This class exists even though you don't know about it, don't warn me if I use it". `#import` actually imports the file so you can use all the methods and instance variables. `@class` is used to save time compiling (importing the whole file makes the compile take more time). You can use `#import` if you want, it will just take longer for your project to build.

Comment: Sometimes, particularly in the case of circular references, you absolutely cannot use #import. @class is a forward declaration of a class, and since it doesn't define the class, can break circular references.

Comment: I thought that #import protected against those, by only adding each file one time.

Answer (score 6):

See [Defining a Class](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html), especially [Referring to Other Classes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF124).