# @class myClass; //what does this does, I can't figure out :s

Tags: iphone, ipad

Everything is in the title, I doesn't understand what the statement below does:

```
#import "x.h"
#import "y.h"
#import "MyAppAppDelegate.h"
#import "z.h"


@implementation x

@class myClass;
```

Could someone explain me using simple words please? I'm quite new to iphone programming :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Words:
It tells the compiler, that there will be a Class named myClass and not to warn you about an unknown class if not really necessary.

[Complex Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import)