# delegate problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

A, B,C is class. 
A define delegate. B define delegate.
C implements delegate.

how do C implements delegate of A by B ?

it means that C want implements A's delegate, but B include A. so it's wrong!

I want to implements A's delegate by B?   what to do in B.   Transfer A'delegate to C ??

please help me!  thanks!

Comment: Question too little words. Question not understand. How answer?

Comment: What does it mean by "how do C implements delegate of A by B ?" ?

Comment: I think you need to post some code of what you have so far.

Comment: post your code atleast to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an issue with circular inclusion, try using @class A or B or C in place of an include.

Answer (score 0):

To elucidate on user441669's (spiffy id!) answer, in your interface file (.h), you should generally declare classes only with @class. Then you #import them in your implementation (.m) file. More info in this [SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597).