# How to import headers recusively in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, recursion, import, include, compilation

Ok this is probably a silly question but why can I do something like this:

```
objectA.h

#import <objectB>
#import <objectC>

objectA.m

#import <ObjectA.h>
```

And in ObjectA.m have access to ObjectB and OBjectC definition ?
It's silly to have to import everything you use in each implementation file.
Am i missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this, and it can occasionally make sense -- *provided* that the definitions are coupled in such a way that they genuinely belong together.

What you *shouldn't* do is introduce bogus compilation dependencies just to save a few keystrokes in some implementation file.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than importing headers in your .h file you could just use the @class declaration for objects you need to declare in your header file, and then in your .m file #import the header files you need.

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, though.

This has been discussed in more detail in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import/323510)

Comment: @Abizem You just saved me hours of headaches.