# Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 

Tags: list, specifier

I have the following Objective-C headers:

```
// Menu.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GameController.h"

@interface Menu : UIImageView {
    GameController *gameController;   // "Expected specifier-qualifier-list
                                      // before GameController"
}

- (void)appear;

@end
```

and

```
// GameController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Menu.h"

@interface GameController : UIView {
    Menu *menu;                       // "Unknown type name 'Menu'"
}

- (void)startLevel0;
- (void)startLevel1;
- (void)startLevel2;

@end
```

When I try to build the project, Xcode (v4) yells at me, saying `Expected specifier-qualifier-list before GameController` and `unknown type name 'Menu'`. I'm sure that they are somehow related, but I have no idea how?

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to have mutually-including header files. Instead of importing Menu.h, use the `@class` directive. Try removing `#import "Menu.h"` and adding `@class Menu` in its place. Ditto for Menu.h (remove GameController include, and add the `@class` directive)

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular reference in your imports. The compiler builds a dependency tree from the import statements so when two Classes rely on each other it doesn't know how to compile one before the other.

Sadly, gcc kicks out a fairly nonsensical error statement when this happens "Expected specifier-qualifier-list". @yan is correct that you should use the @class directive. Check out this question for a solid explanation: [@class vs. #import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import)