# import in objective C

Tags: objective-c

why we import header file in the other file.

Comment: May be answer to this post also answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import.

Answer (score 0):

Its just another name, rather than #include

If you do not import the header file then the compiler doesn't know where some of the things you use in your code come from. Its like importing a dictionary when you are writing in a foreign language, without the dictionary you don't know what everything means or does.

Comment: Just to expand a little on Antwan's answer, `#import` and `#include` both do a very similar job, with the difference being that `#import` makes sure that the imported file is only imported once, but `#include` will include the contents of a file twice if you `#include` it twice.

Comment: @Mac didn't know that, thats pretty cool. Kinda explains why I never got any errors after the 900th call to #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

Comment: that's pretty much exactly it :) Saves the hassle of include guards like you find plastered throughout typical C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

In general "importing" (including) source files/header files is meant to let the current file "see" the objects defined in the imported one.