# Xcode: very strange error subclassing my own class

Tags: iphone, xcode, subclassing

I have an iPhone app with a custom class, `Detail`, a subclass of `UIViewController` that I created.

I need to make a subclass of `Detail`, and I want to to call it `ActivityDetail`. So I wrote the following in my ActivityDetail.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Detail.h"

@interface ActivityDetail : Detail {

}

@end
```

The problem is that I'm getting a compiler error telling me this:

> error: cannot find interface
>   declaration for 'Detail', superclass
>   of 'ActivityDetail'

And the strange thing is: I can change the superclass from `Detail` to `UIView` (for example), compile getting many errors (obviously), and then change the superclass to `Detail` again and everything works fine! But if I then change anything to the `Detail` class the problem comes back from the beginning...

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is recommended to not import classes beyond the default Foundation or UIKit imports in your header files. Instead you should do something similar:

Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Detail;

@interface ActivityDetail : Detail {

}

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "ActivityDetail.h"
#import "Detail.h"

@implementation ActivityDetail

@end
```

This allows your header to "know" about additional classes without forcing all "importers" of that header to also import everything it imports.

---

[Here is a great reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import), and a great answer, regarding the usage of `@class` and `#import`.

Answer (score 8):

Erm you are importing Detail as `Dettaglio.h`. Probably the compiler is not fluent in Italian.

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the .h where Detail is declared?

```
  #import "Detail.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either #import "Detail.h" or subclass from Dettaglio (depends on whichever one your Detail class is actually named.