# Objective-C forward declarations vs. #imports

Tags: objective-c, ios, import, include, forward-declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@class vs. #import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import)

In Objective-C, what are the best practices for using forward declarations (of classes or protocols) vs. `#import`-ing files? And why are forward declarations recommended at all if `#import` ensures no file is included more than once? I'm thinking of iOS app development in particular, but I assume this applies to Objective-C in general.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My rule of thumb is: If a forward declaration is sufficient, I use it. Otherwise I import the full declaration with `#import`.

This is mainly from my experience with large projects where the careless use of `#import` (or `#include`) can easily lead to situation where the compiler has to compile more than a million lines of code for each non-header file and where minor changes in a single header file trigger tons of recompilation. As a consequence, compile the code takes a long time.