# Calling UIViewController method that imports AppDelegate from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have a BaseViewController that all my UiViewController extend.

This BaseViewController also uses AppDelegate and therefor I import it like this:

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;  
}
```

In `AppDelegate`, I need to use a method `applicationDidBecomeActive`. In the method I would like to use a method of BaseViewController.

So I imported the BaseViewController:

`#import "BaseViewController.h"` but then I get a compilation error in `BaseViewController` :

```
Unkown type AppDelegate
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your .h file, add this line:

```
@class AppDelegate
```

at top  Then re-try

Comment: Well this was the correct answer. But can you please explain why?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872154/what-does-class-do-in-ios-4-development