# Difference between #import and @class

Tags: ios, xcode, class, import

i recently watched a tutorial where the speaker said that it makes no difference if you use:

```
#import "Class.h"
```

or:

```
@class Class;
```

And i have to say, my apps work the one way or the other. 
But there have to be a difference right? So thought i ask you guys.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872154/what-does-class-do-in-ios-4-development

Comment: `@class` purely makes the symbol known as an Objective-C class, so you can declare pointers of that type.  `#import "Class.h"` copies into your file all the lines of the .h file, so all the properties and fields and methods of the class are accessible.

Comment: (It's totally untrue that it "makes no difference" which you use.  I'm hoping you simply misinterpreted what the tutorial said or misunderstood the context.  If not, I wouldn't trust the tutorial at all.)

Comment: (You most often see `@class` in .h files, to avoid having to include the referenced class's .h when only declaring pointers of that type.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253051/whats-the-difference-between-import-and-class-and-when-should-i-use-one-over and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import/322627#322627

Answer (score 5):

As per Apple documentation :

> @class allows you to declare that a symbol is an Objective-c class
>   name without the need to #import the header file that defines the
>   class.
>
> You would use this where you only need the class name defined for the
>   purposes of declaring a pointer to the class or a method parameter of
>   the class, and you do not need to access any methods, fields, or
>   properties in the class.
>
> It saves a minuscule amount of compile time vs the #import, and it
>   sometimes helps avoid messy include circularity issues.

Great answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872154/what-does-class-do-in-ios-4-development)

for example when you creat a protocol:

```
@class yourCustomView;

@protocol yourCustomViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void) somethingDidInView:(UIView*)view;

@end

@interface yourCustomView : FIView
```