# Objective-C Cannot find interface declaration

Tags: objective-c, interface, import

I have been scratching my head for awhile trying to figure this one out.

I have the following .h files

```
//ClassA.h
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA {
}

@property SomeEnum blah;

@end

//ClassB.h
#import "ClassA.h"

typedef enum SomeEnum
{
     value1,
     value2
}SomeEnum;

@interface ClassB {
}

@property SomeEnum otherblah;

@end

@interface ClassA (Category) {
}

@end
```

I think the problem is that ClassA needs SomeEnum from ClassB and so it needs to import it, and ClassB needs ClassA for its category so it needs to import it.  Is there a problem with them importing each other?  Do I need to include a third class?

Here are the compiler errors I'm getting:

```
In ClassB.h: Cannot find interface declaration for 'ClassA'
In ClassA.h: Unknown type name 'SomeEnum'
```

**EDIT:**  I got it to work by moving the category declaration into ClassA and then having an @class ClassA in ClassB.h...but I'm still not sure why it wouldn't work in the first place

Comment: This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import

Comment: Is that the entire `ClassB.h` file?  Is it empty except for the import statement (and comments)?

Comment: No it's not... I will edit my post to include more relevant info

Comment: Is @interface ClassA(Category) actually supposed to be within ClassB? I think that is not legal objective C.

Comment: I can definitely declare categories for other classes.  I'm pretty sure at least... It's done other places in my code

Comment: If your code is exactly as it is above, then this is not legal objective C. You need an @end before the category on ClassA.

Comment: Sorry, typo, I do have that @end there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have (non-category declaration):

```
@interface ClassB

@end
```

declared anywhere, usually in `ClassB.h`?
Or a forward declaration:

```
@class ClassB
```

in `ClassA.h`?

---

Try this for your `ClassA.h`:

```
//ClassA.h

@class ClassB

@interface ClassB (Category)
+ (id)classMethod
@end
```

Then put `#import "ClassB.h"` in `ClassA.m`.

---

You should put this in `ClassA.h`:

```
@interface ClassA (Category) {
}

@end
```

And then the:

```
@implementation ClassA (Category)
```

in `ClassA.m` above the non-category `@implementation ClassA`.

---

Personally, I create seperate files for categories.  For example, this is in UIView-Extended.h:

```
@interface UIView (UIView_Extended)

enum {
    UIViewAutoresizingHorizontal = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | 
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin),
    UIViewAutoresizingVertical = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | 
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin),
    UIViewAutoresizingAll = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | 
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | 
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAutoresizing;

- (UIView *)findFirstResponder;
- (UIView *)setFirstResponder:(NSUInteger)viewTag;
- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)nextPrevious:(id)sender;

@end
```

And then in `UIView-Extended.m`:

```
#import "UIView-Extended.h"

@implementation UIView (UIView_Extended)

- (UIView *)findFirstResponder {
    if ([self isFirstResponder]) {
        return self;
    }

    for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
        UIView *firstResponder = [subview findFirstResponder];
        if (firstResponder) {
            return firstResponder;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UIView *)setFirstResponder:(NSUInteger)viewTag {
    if (self.tag == viewTag) {
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
        return self;
    }
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        UIView *v = [subview setFirstResponder:viewTag];
        if (v) {
            return v;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [[self findFirstResponder] resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)nextPrevious:(id)sender {
    UIView *responder = [self findFirstResponder];  
    if (!responder) return;
    NSInteger newTag;
    NSInteger tagMod = 1;
    if (sender) {
        tagMod = (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex ? 1 : -1);
    }
    UIView *v = [self viewWithTag:responder.tag + tagMod];
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] || [v isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        newTag = responder.tag + tagMod;
        [self setFirstResponder:newTag];
    } else {
        //  do something else... but what??
    }
}

@end
```

Then, in my Prefix file (`Project-Prefix.pch`):

```
#import "UIView-Extended.h"
```

Comment: Try putting `@class ClassB` just above `@interface ClassB (Category)` in your `ClassA.h` file.

Comment: Updated post to include more details

Comment: Thanks, can you also provide the exact error/warning you are getting?  I have also updated my answer with:  Try putting the Category declaration in ClassA.h instead of ClassB.h.

Comment: I suppose I could do that but there are other places in my code that do it this way so for parity's sake I would prefer to do it this way.  The other places in the code don't have this cross dependency however...

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to break out your dependencies. Put the definition of `enum SomeEnum` in one header file, then include an import for that header in `ClassA.h` and `ClassB.h`. In `ClassA.h` remove the import of `ClassB.h`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

you should import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` in any object contains "interface declaration"

e.g:
UIImage
NSDate
etc..