# Subclass issue in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In my case, UIViewController B is a subclass of UIViewController A. B can surely access all the methods and variables from A, since B is subclassing from A (i.e. A is the parent of B).

However, A needs a variable from B. Is there possible to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about accessing actual variable values at runtime? If so there are a few options, e.g. notifications, saving data to nsuserdefaults, etc.

Comment: I want A (parent) can access the instance variables which set by B (child) in runtime. How to design and code that?

Comment: @Ankit Srivastava, would you mind explain it more?

Comment: The superclass should not know anything about the subclass. Can you please detail the scenario you're dealing with? In particular why the superclass would need to access the subclass' variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/322627/919545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you need this type of relations - your design is wrong. I mean - you do not need inheritance relationship in you case, but something like aggregation or composition. For example your type of relations breaks The Liskov Substitution Principle.

BUT. Objective C accepts reverse relationships. You can use delegates (@protocol) to describe interfaces which can retrieve some data from unknown objects who accepts this @protocol.

So, in your case class B should conform a protocol which provide access to some properties of B. And A should be able to work with this protocol, i.e. to know getters which A needs.

Answer (score 0):

Add that variable as a default in subclass A. Then it's also available in subclass B?

If that's something you don't want, then I suppose there is something wrong with your design?

Comment: What I want is that A (parent) needs to access the instance variables which set by B (child) in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If the instance variable declared in the subclass has a getter method, any method in the superclass could always ask an object of its class if it respondsToSelector: for that getter method, and if so, call it to get the value of the instance variable.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show me some sample code of your idea? It would be a great help to me.