# ios class not found "Expected a type"

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm getting two problems in my `FooterSelectorView.h` and I have no idea why. One is a warning while the other is an error. For some reason xcode doesn't recognize `FooterArchiveItemView` so I'm not able to type my object as that which is causing other propblems. Has anyone ever seen anything like this before? How can I fix it?

**FooterSelectorView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FooterArchiveItemView.h"

@interface FooterSelectorView : UIImageView

// #warning Type of property 'activeItem' does not match type of accessor 'setActiveItem:'
@property (nonatomic, retain) FooterArchiveItemView *activeItem;

// #error Expected a type
- (void)setActiveItem:(FooterArchiveItemView *)activeItem_;
- (void)update;
- (CGPoint)absoluteCenterOf:(UIView *)obj;

@end
```

*Related Classes*

**FooterArchiveItemView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AutosizeableView.h"
#import "FooterArchiveView.h"

typedef void (^ DayBlock)(void);

@interface FooterArchiveItemView : AutosizeableView {
    DayBlock dayBlock;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *day;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *bullet;

- (void)setDayBlock:(DayBlock)block;

@end
```

**AutosizeableView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AutosizeableView : UIView

@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing I'd suggest is that you conform to the Obj-C practice, that, within header interface files, rather than importing custom classes, you forward-declare them. For example, in FooterSelectorView.h, rather than:

```
#import "FooterArchiveItemView.h"
```

Forward-declare the class:

```
@class FooterArchiveItemView
```

Then, in the implementation file (FooterSelectorView.m), you import. Observing the practice may not actually solve your issue in this case (I don't know exactly what's happening, personally I'd want to see a bit more code to hazard a guess), but it might help isolate the issue for you.

The noted exception to this rule is Apple's frameworks - those are imported into headers.

Comment: I tried this with no success then I just went around adding this to a number of classes and still nothing. However, then I commented all the class declarations out and it worked. so odd.. -- Is this just a best practice or something?

Comment: Glad it got you somewhere, here's several good explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import

Comment: Forward declarations are much more safe than imports in the header files, unless you safely construct your header files in such a way that a circular reference causes no problems (header A imports class B and header B imports class A). I assume this is solved through the forward declarations, where the headers (which are imported in .m files) are not doing any importing themselves, meaning they can't get stuck in a loop.

Comment: Thank you, it was the solution of my problem. I had a identifier not found exception. By removing #import and adding @class the problem was solved.