# Objective C - Error: 'Expected a type'

Tags: objective-c, import, header-files, forward-declaration, circular-dependency

I'm getting a very strange error on something that I would have thought to be simple.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GameObject.h"


@interface GameController : NSObject 

@property (strong) GLKBaseEffect * effect;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray * gameObjects;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray * objectsToRemove;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray * objectsToAdd;


+ (GameController *) sharedGameController;
- (void) tick:(float)dt;
- (void) initializeGame: (ViewController*) viewcontroller;//ERROR: EXPECTED A TYPE

- (void) createObject:(Class) objecttype atPoint:(CGPoint)position;
- (void) deleteObject:(GameObject*) object atPoint:(CGPoint)position;
- (void) manageObjects;

@end
```

Why would it question whether or not 'ViewController' is a type? It's a class that I've correctly implemented. It has also been imported.

EDIT ***

Here is the ViewController.m class if it helps.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[GameController sharedGameController] initializeGame:self];
}

@end
```

EDIT 2 ******

and the ViewController.h file

```
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
#import "GameController.h" 

@interface ViewController : GLKViewController

@end
```

Comment: How is `ViewController` defined?

Comment: This might help you, similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9607607/1422070

Comment: Maybe inside the .h file you mispelled the class name.

Comment: toss a `@class ViewController;` above the @interface

Comment: @GradyPlayer Why, it is already included? `#import "ViewController.h"` No need to forward declare it.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist that certainly isn't a requirement that the file named ViewController.h contain an interface for the class ViewController

Answer (score 53):

Use a forward declaration: `@class ViewController;` in place of `#import "ViewController.h"`. The import is usually unnecessary in another header in Objective-C.

If you use `ViewController` in `GameController`, then you can add the import to GameController.m.

**You probably have a circular dependency.**

The basic way to define a circular dependency is:

- `GameController.h` imports `ViewController.h`
- `ViewController.h` imports `GameController.h`

Which one will be seen first depends on the order of declaration in the translation, but obviously one will have to come first because in this case the headers disagree as to which must come first.

In a real codebase, you may `#import "ViewController.h"` in many source files. This creates very complex dependencies. These dependencies are largely unnecessary in ObjC -- you can use forward declarations most of the time in a header (and it will improve your build times).

So I explained the simplest case, but what happens when 15 headers `#import ViewController.h`? Well, you would have to track down which header is introducing that circular dependency for that translation. If you don't manage dependencies well, then you may have to step through dozens (or hundreds) of files. Sometimes, it's easiest to just review the preprocessed output for that translation (e.g. the offending `*.m` file). If dependencies are not minimized, that output could be hundreds of thousands of lines (and your build times could be 20 or more times faster if it were managed correctly). So the complexity of locating circular dependencies quickly goes up in large codebases; the more you `#import` and `#include` in the headers. Using forward declarations in headers (where possible) solves this problem.

**Example**

So given your header in the OP, you could rewrite it as:

GameController.h

```
// includes
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// forwards required by this header    
@class GameObject;
@class GLKBaseEffect;
@class ViewController;

// header declarations
@interface GameController : NSObject 

@property (strong) GLKBaseEffect * effect;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray * gameObjects;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray * objectsToRemove;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray * objectsToAdd;


+ (GameController *) sharedGameController;
- (void) tick:(float)dt;
- (void) initializeGame: (ViewController*) viewcontroller;//ERROR: EXPECTED A TYPE

- (void) createObject:(Class) objecttype atPoint:(CGPoint)position;
- (void) deleteObject:(GameObject*) object atPoint:(CGPoint)position;
- (void) manageObjects;

@end
```

GameController.m

```
#import "GameController.h"
#import "ViewController.h" // << if you need it in this source
#import "GameObject.h" // << if you need it in this source

@implementation GameController
...
```

Then you can apply the same treatment to ViewController.h (which is importing GameController.h).

Comment: I included the forward declaration, and I imported the header in the '.m' file. I still get the same error.

Do you mind explaining the 'circular dependency' issue a bit more?

Comment: My project has that circular dependency. How should I go about correcting it?

Comment: So I changed all my imports to class forward declarations and the error disappeared. What exactly is happening when I do this? Is it recommended that this is how I handle all class importing?

Comment: @user2577959 forwards in headers are much better than imports. in some cases, you will need the import (e.g. the class you derive from must be visible). a forward declaration of `@class ViewController` just tells the compiler "there is an objc type with the name ViewController", and once it knows it does not need to see the class declaration. if you want to create use ViewController's interface in a translation, then you import.

Comment: @user2577959 "when to import" has answered here on SO… (looking) you're welcome

Comment: @user2577959: Here's the basic issue: When you write `#import something`, the compiler essentially takes the contents of that `something` and copy-pastes it into the file it's compiling. But when two files both `#import` each other, this is impossible, because one has to go before the other, so one of them ends up disappointed and you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the class interface defined inside `ViewController.h` is also spelled as "`ViewController`"?

I did a quick test by creating a `ViewController.h` class in my project, but renamed the interface to `ViewControllers` inside it and got the same error as you.

Comment: Could you post the declarations for ViewController?