# Expected a Type Error iOS in my code

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code please explain me the problem...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AudioPlayerModel : NSObject
**-(AVPLayer*) getPlayer;**                   //error expected a type
@end
```

Please tell me the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey its `AVPlayer*` not `AVPLayer*`...  you've put L caps...

But for clarity check
["Expected a type" error pointing to the return type of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105688/expected-a-type-error-pointing-to-the-return-type-of-a-method)

and 
[Objective C - Error: 'Expected a type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624839/objective-c-error-expected-a-type)

and many similar Questions...

Answer (score 2):

You've put `AVPLayer` with a capital L.  You need `AVPlayer`.