# iPhone+Difference Between writing @classname & #import"classname.h" in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@class vs. #import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import)

I am Really confused with this,Whats the difference between writing @classname & #import"classname.h" .When Do we go for @classname?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import) and in the Objective-C Programming Language documentation on [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF123)

Answer (score 0):

`@classname` is a `forward declaration`. Nothing gets imported, it just informes the compiler, that the class *will* exist on runtime.

`#import` will actually import the other class -> you can imagine it as a copy it into the file. so the imported classes will get compiled before the one, that it is written in.

Answer (score 0):

`@classname` just tells the compiler that the class `classname` exists.

`#import` really imports the header file so that the compiler not only knows that it exists, but also how it looks. (like ivars, methods etc...)

Answer (score 0):

The @classname just let's the compiler know that the class exists however you'll still need to import the corresponding .h.  You can use the @classname in the .h and then import the class in the .m and this will allow you to avoid circular references.  You can read more about it here [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

`@className` directive is introduced to overcome **cyclic reference** of classes, it is also known as **Forward Declaration**

`@class` will just inform the compiler that there is a class named "@className yourClass" no need to worry about that class and in runtime it just refer that class and executes.

`#import "className"` will keep a copy of that particular class.