# Delegate method can't reference its own class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView subclass called NumberPickerView. I'm writing a delegate method for it. The compiler won't let me pass an instance of NumberPickerView as an parameter in that method. What am I missing?

```
@protocol NumberPickerViewDelegate

-(void) numberPickerDidChangeSelection:(NumberPickerView *)numberPickerView;
//error: expected a type

@end


@interface NumberPickerView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
     id <NumberPickerViewDelegate> delegate;
}
```

Comment: Injectios answer is by far the most correct solution.  With that said, how useful is `numberPickerDidChangeSelection:`?  Wouldn't `numberPicker:(NumberPickerView *)numberPickerView didChangeSelection:(id)selection;` (where `id` is replaced by whatever represents the selection) be far more useful?  Even a separate argument for the `from` and `to` change might be useful.

Comment: Possibly, but I don't really need to know the value at the time it's changed - just which picker has changed. In my current implementation NumberPickerView has a value property, and there are several on screen at once. I am getting the picker's value directly from its property, at the time I need it, so just need to know which one has been changed. Your implementation would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it CAN. At that point compiler doesn't know about `NumberPickerView` class

```
@class NumberPickerView;
```

add it over protocol declaration to let compiler know about that class... It's called `forward declaration`.

For better understanding check this out:

[iPhone+Difference Between writing @classname & #import"classname.h" in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926847/iphonedifference-between-writing-classname-importclassname-h-in-xcode)

OR

move protocol declaration below the class `NumberPickerView` definition but in that case you should also add at top:

```
@protocol NumberPickerViewDelegate;
```

Not to get warnings using `id<NumberPickerViewDelegate>delegate`

Answer (score 3):

You can change parameter type to id instead of NumberPickerView * and pass any class object afterword as bellow

```
@protocol NumberPickerViewDelegate

-(void) numberPickerDidChangeSelection:(id)numberPickerView;

@end


@interface NumberPickerView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
     id <NumberPickerViewDelegate> delegate;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would compile. But a "wrong delegate" would no longer be detected by the compiler and cause a runtime exception later.