# "Attempting to use the forward class 'Game' as superclass of 'MathGame'" in Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, import, forward-declaration

I'm making a Cocos2d game for iphone, and I have my main game mode, `Game`, which inherits from `CCLayer`.

I'm trying to make another game mode, `MathGame`, which inherits from `Game`, but when I try to compile, I get this error in `MathGame.h`:

> Attempting to use the forward class 'Game' as superclass of 'MathGame'

I get the error even if the implementation and interface of `MathGame` are empty. And it only happens if I try to include `MathGame.h` in another file.

Here's the code for the Game class:

```
// Game.h
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import "SplashScreenLayer.h"

@interface Game : CCLayer
    // A bunch of stuff
@end
```

The new game type:

```
// MathGame.h
#import "Game.h"

@interface MathGame : Game
@end
```

And the main menu that includes both:

```
// SplashScreen.h
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Game.h"
#import "MathGame.h"
#import "HowToPlayLayer.h"
#import "AboutLayer.h"

@interface SplashScreenLayer : CCLayer
    // A bunch of stuff
@end
```

I can't find anything helpful online. Any ideas?

Comment: MathGame.h imports Game.h?  (If that's not it, you may need to show some code.)

Comment: Please show the relevant `@interface` sections. Usually this happens when you forget to #import headers and instead just use `@class` instead.

Comment: I trust there's a `@end` somewhere after `@interface Game : CCLayer`?

Comment: There is. Just left out the meat of the files

Comment: Do you do any old-school, C-style "#ifndef XXX #define XXX" in order to ensure the header is included only once? If so, this might cause that issue, and it's unnecessary with the #import keyword.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You simply have an import cycle:

1. `Game` imports `SplashScreenLayer`
2. `SplashScreenLayer` imports `MathGame`
3. `MathGame` imports `Game`

Your solution:

Leave the `import` inside the `MathGame`, and change the other imports to [@class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import).

To sum it up:

```objectivec
// Game.h
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@class SplashScreenLayer;
@interface Game : CCLayer
    // A bunch of stuff
@end

The new game type:

// MathGame.h
#import "Game.h"

@interface MathGame : Game
@end

And the main menu that includes both:

// SplashScreen.h
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "HowToPlayLayer.h"
#import "AboutLayer.h"

@class Game;
@class MathGame;
@interface SplashScreenLayer : CCLayer
    // A bunch of stuff
@end
```

---

With your question answered above, let me explain a few things I already know from reading about forward declerations and import cycles:

First, go read about them! They are a very important part of Objective-C, and you don't want to miss it!

Secondly, use @class whenever you need that class for private variables or method parameters. Use imports for inheritance and **strong** properties.

Thirdly, don't forget to `#import` your forwarded classes in the implementation file!

Comment: HI. Regarding Thirdly, don't forget to #import your forwarded classes in the implementation file! - do you mean that in the .m files I have to import all the classes that I defined as @class ? why?

Comment: @Odelya Because using @ class only notifies your class that there is a class that exists with that name, but it doesn't expose the methods and properties it has

Comment: well explained. i missed hat.

Comment: @Mazyod
If my super class in swift i.g. Game and MathGame is in Objective-c, How its would work because Game.h is not exist due to swift class i.e class Game: NSObject

Answer (score 1):

In my case,I user the xx class and use the @class but not #import the .h file.and the compile complain..