# Attempting to use the forward class UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, superclass, forward

My project was working fine till yesterday but today I am getting 22 errors and all are saying that "Attempting to use the forward class UIViewController as superclass of (UIActivityController/UIAlertController/etc)".
I don't understand what is the issue here. Can anyone suggest solution. I am using Xcode 9.2

[image]

Comment: can you post any of your code?

Comment: Yes I can,, but I dont know which code will be useful

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819764/attempting-to-use-the-forward-class-game-as-superclass-of-mathgame-in-coco Take a look at diff of what changed since yesterday (assuming that yesterday everything worked well). Did  you change any imports?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.. actually it seems it was an error of xcode. I have installed Xcode 9.4 and the issues disappeared with single line of code. Strange but worked for me.