# Unknown Type even though Im importing

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm getting this error,

```
Unknown type name ArrowWrapper
```

from within `BoxSprite.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "BoxSum.h"
#import "ArrowWrapper.h"

@interface BoxSprite : CCSprite {

}
@property ArrowWrapper* arrowItem;
@end
```

Also, `ArrowWrapper.h` contains this.

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "BoxSprite.h"

@interface ArrowWrapper : CCMenuItem {

}

@property BoxSprite* box;
@end
```

The error used to be in ArrowWrapper saying it couldnt find BoxSprite until I did a clean, and now it's in BoxSprite saying it can't find ArrowWrapper.

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a recursive import: "BoxSprite.h" imports "ArrowWrapper.h" and vice versa.

You have to remove one of the `import` statements and use `@class` instead. For example in "BoxSprite.h" replace

```
#import "ArrowWrapper.h"
```

by

```
@class ArrowWrapper;
```

You can then import "ArrowWrapper.h" in the implementation file "BoxSprite.m", if necessary.

**Detailed explanation:** Xcode displays the error in "BoxSprite.h", but the error actually occurs when "ArrowWrapper.m" is compiled:

1. "ArrowWrapper.m" imports "ArrowWrapper.h".
2. "ArrowWrapper.h" imports "BoxSprite.h" before defining the `ArrowWrapper` class.
3. "BoxSprite.h" imports "ArrowWrapper.h": But "ArrowWrapper.h" is *already marked as imported*, so the compiler does not read it again.
4. Therefore, when reading "BoxSprite.h", the `ArrowWrapper` class has not been defined yet, causing the compiler error.

Replacing `import` by `@class` solves the problem, because it makes the `ArrowWrapper` class known to the compiler at that point without reading the interface file.

Comment: @Austin: `@class` makes the class known to the compiler without actually importing the interface file. It is a common method to resolve #import "loops".

Comment: @Austin: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import for more details.

Comment: @Austin: See also my addition to the answer, it should explain the problem and solution in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with import statements.

You are importing `#import "ArrowWrapper.h"` in BoxSprite.h and importing `#import "BoxSprite.h"` in `ArrowWrapper.h`

So Change the BoxSprite.h like :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "BoxSum.h"

@class ArrowWrapper;
@interface BoxSprite : CCSprite {

}
@property ArrowWrapper* arrowItem;
@end
```