# How to fix Xcode expected type error

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Today when I opened up Xcode project and built it for the iOS simulator. Everything was working fine yesterday but this morning there is a compilation error.

The following line is highlighted red in a header file and the message next to it says "Expected a type".

```
-(void) addObstacle:(Obstacle*) obstacle;
```

The bit of code hasn't changed in a few days so I'm not really sure why theres now an error.

I have imported Obstacle.h and this is the Obstacle class header:

```
#import "kobold2d.h"

@interface Obstacle : CCNode {
    int posXInGrid;
    int posYInGrid;

    CCSprite* sprite;
}

@property (nonatomic) int posXInGrid;
@property (nonatomic) int posYInGrid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite* sprite;

@end
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with circular references in your imports. Could the error be in `kobold2d.h`?

Comment: Please post your whole .h file where error is comming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move `#import "Obstacle.h"` from the interface (.h) to the implementation file (.m).

Then add @class Obstacle; at the top of the interface file.

If this fixes the problem you do have a circular import. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import) to learn why this fixes it.  @class is preferable over #importing class headers whenever possible.