# What does @class mean in objc files

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I have noticed that when going through a lot of the framework public header files, there are things like : ex :

```
@class UIImage;

NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UIColor : NSObject <NSSecureCoding, NSCopying> {
    @private
}
```

I understand the NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) and the rest, but I don't understand the use of the @class keyword.

If someone could explain the use, and how it is used I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import

Comment: I'm not being rude, but what does my rep have to do with this question? It is becuase i have answered questions for many different things and people said they were right...i did search for it, and didn't see anything. Excuse me for making a mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `forward declaration`: it basically tells the compiler that the class UIImage exists, without specifying what exactly it looks like.

It is recommended to use `forward declaration` of classes instead of importing header in header files to avoid coupling of classes and improve compilation time.