# Circular reference in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create instance of classes in each class. But xCode does not give permission.

For example;

I have class A and I have created instance of class B, if I create instance of A in B. It shows an error that the class is not found do you mean this class.So, i am not able to add it.

Could you please explain this situation and is there a solution for it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: Don't forget to `#import` the class A header (.h) into the class B implementation (.m) and the class B header into class A implementation. And use `@class ClassB` in your .h if you want to use them as properties. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to #import each class .h file into the other class .m file. If you import each .h into the .h files then you will have a circularity which won't work. If you need a public property for the instances then use @class instead of #import in the .h files (which is good practice anyway to limit scope and visibility).