# Objective-C forward declaration vs #import in model hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, import, forward-declaration

I know that there are many questions on stackoverflow about the differences between @class forward declarations and #imports - and I do understand that it is mostly compiler optimization and reducing circular import problems.

My question is more about coding style in the following circumstances, say for instance I have a model structure like below.

```
// Classroom.h
@class Teacher;

@interface ClassRoom : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Teacher *teacher;
- (NSArray *)students;

@end



// Teacher.h
@interface Teacher : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;

@end
```

Now, when I am using this in another class I would need to import both Teacher.h and ClassRoom.h if I wanted to access the firstName property via

```
teacherObject.firstName
```

Whereas if I used #import Teacher.h instead of @class Teacher; I would only have to import #Teacher.

So my main question is if this is a reasonable occasion to use an import instead of a forward declaration? The actual model structure I am using in my project is much more complex than this and I often have to import 5-10 different model classes at the beginning of my implementation files (in the controllers). While this does not hurt anything it does become frustrating and make the source code longer. I would love to hear opinions on this from Objective-C veterans.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@class vs. #import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import)

Comment: @Avt thank you for the link. I did find that question (and many more) while searching StackOverflow.com but it is not exactly what I am asking. I am more curious if it is good practice to use #imports in a deep model hierarchy to prevent tens of lines of imports in all of the controller classes that use the model. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I always do it like apple does: I 'never' cascade imports but I usually have a 'wrapper h file' ...

like when I have FeatFooA.h FeatFooB.h FeatFooC.h
I also have a AllFeaturesFoo.h

Comment: an umbrella header so to speak

Comment: I *think*, but can't find the video to back me up, that making these precompiled headers (.pch) would also give a performance increase at compile time.

Comment: those wouldnt be pchs at all. You shouldnt only rely on pchs. Although they increase performance and it might make sense to add those to the pch later

Comment: pchs do increase performance but make the whole thing more fragile. google the benefits/drawbacks of pchs for that

Answer (score 1):

I personally find it nice/handy to explicitly show dependencies with `#import`s in `.m` files.

However, files that are generic for the app, and could be used in (almost) all modules, form an exception.

1. In such case you could use one common header where you `#import` all those generic headers; and then `#import` this single header in every module.
2. Alternatively you could put this list of generic `#import`s in your `AppName-Prefix.pch` file.  (Or even do one `#import` of a common header (see above).)  In that case you don't have to `#import` anything in your modules.  But I personally don't like hidden/implicit stuff; so I'd rather choose the first option.

Then with regards to your example: It may make sense to create a `School.h`, which would then be the only header that's needed.  If things are dependent on each other, because it's all part of a certain concept ('school' in this example), it's good to keep the interface simple.  I know this sounds vague, but I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question is about code quality and best coding practices.

IMHO `#import` is more convenient since you will never receive a compiler error *"Unknown Class"*.

BUT there is one case where I will not recommend to use `#import`. Assume you have several layers in your app. Lets say: Network, Controller and View (GUI). For some reasons you **have to** access GUI class MyProgressView from Network layer (for example you are using third-party lib):

```
@interface MyNetworkClass : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyProgressView *progressView;
@end
```

If you will use `#import` any Network-layer class that imports MyNetworkClass.h will also know about MyProgressView. It is contrary to responsibility sharing! So in this case `@class` will be better.