# Why @class DataViewController in ModelController.h?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a page based application.

What @class DataViewController  means in ModelController.h ? Why #import "DataViewController.h" in ModelController.m is not enough ?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DataViewController;

@interface ModelController : NSObject <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

- (DataViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard;
- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController;

@end
```

Comment: `@class` to remove circular reference. (Eg: Class A imports Class B and Class B imports Class A. To avoid circular reference in such conditions we can use @class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@class DataViewController;
```

is for

```
-(DataViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
                                  storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard;
```

`@class` is a forward declaration that tells the compiler to be a little forgiving to this method declaration that is meant to return a `DataViewController` object, and defer the handling to the implementation part.
You will eventually need `#import "DataViewController.h"` in `ModelController.m`.

Well... you could put `#import "DataViewController.h"` but... if `DataViewController.h` itself has an `#import "ModelController.h"` statement then the compiler will go in a circular import loop.

---

As for:

> Why `#import "DataViewController.h"` in `ModelController.m` is not enough ?

1. You're publicly declaring a method `-viewControllerAtIndex:storyboard:` in `ModelController.h`.

   - This tells classes importing `ModelController` that it provides such a method.
2. This method returns a `DataViewController` object *and since the possibility of `DataViewController.h` importing `ModelController.h` exists*

   - You need `@class DataViewController;` in `ModelController.h`
3. Since `@class` is only a forward declaration, you need `#import "DataViewController.h"` in `ModelController.m`

If... the method is used within `ModelController` class only then you need not declare the method in the `.h` and thereby dropping the need for the `@class DataViewController;` statement.

---

Also, I like this *generic* answer on [@class vs. #import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322627/2857130)