# How to add prefix file in xcode 5 existing project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

Hope all of you'll be fine. 
I am doing a project in which i need to add core-data functionality. I am working on xcode-5. I need to add pch file in xcode-5 existing project as it was missing in the project. I have searched a lot on net to add pch file in xcode-5 but only found procedures to add pch file in xcode-6. which is totally different with xocde-5. Please provide step by step help to add pch file in xcode 5 (as I am new to ios). Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a pch file, it's only ever a convenience. Not every file in your project needs the import so you should import just where you need it...

Comment: Dear @Wain, Thanks for your such a quick reply. Actually i really don't know that while using core-data where it will be needed to import Coredata.h. So thats why i need to import pch file in my project.

Comment: Strictly, you don't need to import Coredata.h anywhere. Import the classes that you use in the files that you use them. If you import more than 5 Core Data files in one file then consider importing Coredata.h instead.

Comment: ok, fine and many thanks for your consideration dear @Wain.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can set the `prefix header`, it has to be done in the `target`'s `build settings`:

In `Xcode` and in your open project, select the project-icon in the upper left corner so you can see the `PROJECT` and the `TARGETS`.

Select the target where you want to add the `prefix header` file. On the right side, select `Build Settings`. In the search field on the right side, type `prefix header` to reveal the setting **`Prefix Header`** quickly 
(and at the left side of the search field, select `ALL`).

The path to put here is either an absolute path or a path relative to the Xcode project-file.

---

Here an example of a prefix header file that I use to share the `DSLog` macro:

```
// Zero-Prefix.pch

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DSLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DSLog(...)
#endif
```